Flutter mutiple flavors with flutter_flavorizr error
I am using flutter_flavorizr library to set up multiple flavors. But I got this error when running the command flutter pub run flutter_flavorizr.
Error:
Executing task ios:xcconfig
Running XcodeprojProcessor: Checking if xcodeproj is installed
Unhandled exception:
Exception: Xcodeproj is not installed. Please install it by running `gem install xcodeproj`
#0      XcodeprojProcessor.execute (package:flutter_flavorizr/src/processors/darwin/xcodeproj_processor.dart:20:7)
#1      QueueProcessor.execute (package:flutter_flavorizr/src/processors/commons/queue_processor.dart:44:17)
#2      Processor.execute (package:flutter_flavorizr/src/processors/processor.dart:144:24)

I tried running gem install xcodeproj in the terminal but I got another error
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'xcodeproj' (>= 0) in any repository


How can I fix it? Thanks!
